# Img Src Location HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have a web with the following structure:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Images
Script
default.aspx
site.master
web.config
```

On `site.master`, I have loaded an image with `<img src="Images/logo1.png" alt="hallmark" />`

So, when I run `default.aspx`, the image is appear. But when I run a page from `Folder1` or `Folder2`, the image is not appear.

How can I make the image is always appear on each page? Since the image is on Master Page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I am using `Resolve.Url`

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you use the path like above it will check for the '**images**' folder within the folder which you are currently running from, if you use the full path like "**C:\Users\user1\Desktop\images\logo1.png**" the image will always appear.

Comment: If your questions is answered please mark it as answered.  :)